# how to use localstorage in electron

Tags: electron

In an electron app, I use `window.loadURL('http://example.com')` to load my website, this website uses `localStorage` to save user data. My question is how to use the `localStorage` with Electron API?

Here is my code :

```
{
      label:'test',
      click:()=>{          
        let object = mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('localStorage.length');
        console.log("localstorage.length:"+JSON.stringify(object));
      }
    }
```

But it will print `localstorage.length:{}`

Answer (score 1):

[`executeJavaScript`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) is an asynchronous function and returns a Promise. You need to either use `async/await` or chain `.then()` to access the value returned by the function.

```js
 // inside an async function
 const object = await mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('localStorage.length');
 console.log(`Localstorage length: ${object}`);
```

or

```js
mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('localStorage.length')
  .then(object => console.log(`Localstorage length: ${object}`));
```

Check out [this example](https://gist.github.com/a5bfe9a0608314af618867a565c51ad6) openable in [Electron Fiddle](https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle). Swap out `loadFile` for `loadURL` with your website, and you should be set.